# "The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject" error

Tags: java, json

```
public JSONObject getResult(JSONObject obj)
    {
        JSONObject results = obj.getJSONObject("results");
        JSONObject result = obj.getJSONObject("result");
        return result;
    }
```

This is such simple code but I cannot figure out why it won't work.

*The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject* error on both "getJSONObject" methods.

-I know this may be a repeated question but none of the answers on those questions have helped me.

Comment: Probably using the wrong library for the sample code.

Comment: I've imported org.json.simple.*

Comment: You are using the [**wrong library**](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) for the sample code.

Comment: Step #1. Search for the API you think you are using. Step #2. Use that library; or correct the API usage for the library being used

Comment: For comparison, here is the [JSON.simple API that is being imported](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
```